# Retireve a query as a byte array

Tags: c#, mysql

Im trying to retrieve a query as a byte array. Im stuck @ the code though.

```
byte[] temp = QueryFile("SELECT modelFile FROM items WHERE modelName='F_Pants1'");
    public byte[] QueryFile(string queue)
            {
                MySqlCommand command = MySqlCon.CreateCommand();
                MySqlDataReader Reader;
                command.CommandText = queue;
                MySqlCon.Open();
                Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                byte[] thisrow = new byte[1000];
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        thisrow[0] = Convert.ToByte(Reader.GetValue(i).ToString());


                }
                thisrow = thisrow.Remove(thisrow.Length - 1, 1);
                MySqlCon.Close();

                return thisrow;

            }
```

If anyone has an answer, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: functions that accept completed sql queries as strings will lead to sql injection security issues.

Comment: SQL Injection if the  function will get an un-checked strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making it a bit too complicated. Try this instead:

```
       try {
         Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         if (Reader.Read())
          {
              return Reader.GetValue(0) as Byte[];
          }
        } finally {
           MySqlCon.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This is also too complicated - he can just use .ExecuteScalar()

Comment: ill change the function later but it returns null when i query