# Retrieve Images automatically when scan the barcode using mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new to c# programming and trying to do a barcode attendance system. In the system barcode reading is working fine. It retrieves students name and other details automatically after scanning the student ID.

```
 private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
        if (result != null)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
            {
               
                cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM `std_info` where nibm_id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString(); // student id
                    label3.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString(); // student name
                    label4.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString(); // student nic
                    label8.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString(); // student batch
                   

                }
                con.Close();

            }));
           

        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
```

I just want to know how to retrieve a picture from database according to student id and show it after scanning has been done. (I have added a column name `image` with blob image format type in the database)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXMkH.png)

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305673/retireve-a-query-as-a-byte-array

Comment: Side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the `barCode` image path to the database image column. After you could get the image path by the studentId =

> "SELECT image FROM std_info WHERE nibm_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'"

, while `image` has your image path and use PictureBox as

> picture.Image = Image.FromFile('your path gained from database')

and it should works. The only note when you save the path in the database is to change `//` to `////` using `string.replace`.
Sorry for my bad english an get a try if it's your answer.